# Roland midi controller not recognized

Tags: alsa, midi

I was able to use the Pi as a Midi synthesizer for a [Midiplus AKM320](https://www.amazon.com/midiplus-AKM320-MIDI-Keyboard-Controller) controller using `fluidsynth` and `aconnect`. Then I got a larger [Roland A49](https://www.bax-shop.nl/midi-keyboards/roland-a-49bk-midi-keyboard-zwart) midi keyboard, but am unable to get this to work. It shows up with `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0582:0156 Roland Corp.
```

It has no strange `dmesg` output:

```
[    3.261803] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.377288] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0582, idProduct=0156
[    3.386801] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.396664] usb 1-1.3: Product: A-Series Keyboard
[    3.403869] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Roland
```

Problem is that it does NOT show up with `aconnect -i`.

The Roland still works with Ubuntu on my laptop.

About my Raspberry Pi:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #538 PREEMPT Fri Aug 30 20:42:08 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7
```

How do I get this Roland keyboard to work?

(Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the manufacturer with the same name)

---

update:

Looking at [this SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199959/usb-midi-keyboard-oxygen-61-now-not-appearing-in-qjackctl) I tried to load module `snd-seq-midi`, but it made no improvement.

This midi keyboard is not listed in `/proc/asound/cards` and neither by `amidi -l` .

Comment: Is the `snd-usb-audio` module loaded?

Comment: @CL. Good question! It is loaded by the AKM320, but not with the Roland. I loaded it with `modprobe`, which also loaded modules snd_hwdep, snd_usbmidi_lib, snd_pcm and snd. But the Roland is still not recognized with `aconnect -i`

Comment: Any messages in the system log when you're loading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer on a differently phrased question of me [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475430/296434), the solution is to upgrade to the current version of the raspberry pi linux. Support for this Roland keyboard was not yet in the kernel version of 2013.
I just upgraded to the current version of Rasbian and now the Roland is recognized by `aconnect -i`.